# Why doesn't security rule work for specific users in Firebase-Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to secure every user's database and only accessible by its own user.
when I try to access the database through some codes in unity, it gets failed and the permission to access the data gets denied.

My Firebase Security Rule

...

```
 "rules": {
"users": {  
  "$user": {
    ".read": "auth.provider === 'facebook'", 
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $user"
   }
 }}
```

...

In Unity, to write data I use the following code after authenticating the user:
...

```
playerDbRef.Child("users").Child(UserId).Child("User_Info").Child("name").SetValueAsync(UserName);
```

as from the rule, only User x can access data x. but in practice that does not work.
What the problem might be? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're concerned about users being able to read `/users/$user` even if their user id doesn't match what's stored at $user. In the case of these rules, you've made it so that anyone authenticated via Facebook is able to read any value stored under `/users/$user`, and to lock it down you actually want your ".read" rule to be identical with your ".write" rule. *IF* I misinterpreted your issue, you can stop reading now.

A way to validate your rules that's really simple is to use Firebase's Realtime Database simulator built into our web console. I've embedded your sample rules as (changes are formatting and leading {}'s that you omitted):

```
{"rules": {
  "users": {  
    "$user": {
      ".read": "auth.provider === 'facebook'", 
      ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $user"
     }
   }
}}
```

With this simulator you can see that if I try to read when unauthenticated, I'm blocked:
[read unauthenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE6dZ.png)

But when I read as any user, it lets me in:
[read as any facebook user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIwVI.png)

If I click on details, it will tell me exactly why (my auth provider is facebook):
[details of why the rule passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k95vn.png)

On the other hand, you'll see that I can't subsequently write to this node:
[write rejected as any user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ruoS.png)
since your write rule should be correct, unless my user id also matches:
[write accepted as owning user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh8Dg.png)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking time and replying. I found out that the rules were working completely fine and the problem was with Unity itself. In practice Unity can't work well with firebase authentication or read/write data when security rules are applied, unless the project is built on mobile. So by testing it on a mobile device everything worked well for me and meaning the unity editor does not seem to respond to all firebase functions.